# Why got type error :takes 1 position argument but 2 were given?

Tags: python, django

I have faced a problem with my django project. It is as following:

Get Result: `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

My code:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^_get_weather', views._get_weather, name='_get_weather')
```

**views.py**

```
def _get_weather(request):
    r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=$API&q=Hongkong')
    s = r.read().decode('utf-8')
    j = json.loads(s)
    temp='Current tempearture: {:.2f}'.format(j['main']['temp'] - 273.15)
    return HttpRequest(temp)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your view function should return an [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) not an [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).